# the code execution cannot proceed because kpathsea631.dll was not found

Tags: r, visual-studio, latex, rstudio, r-markdown

I failed to compile a R Markdown file and the error message is "The code execution cannot proceed because kpathsea631.dll was not found". 
I updated the Visual C++ Redistributable and reinstalled R, Rstudio and MiKTeX. All of these methods failed. Could any help me with this? 
I am using Win10 system.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message using TinyTex instead of MiKTex. Like you, I also deinstalled very much and installed it again but I think basically it is already sufficient to reinstall TinyTex (as long as the error message stems from pdflatex.exe).

So, `remove.packages("tinytex")`, go to the folder `C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/TinyTex` and make sure you delete/deinstall it as well.

When installing tinytex again, make sure you follow the steps explained here: https://yihui.org/tinytex/